# Is it possible to trigger Mouseevents by a divcontainer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I have an div Element with the ID mypointer, wich has an absolute position. I animate this div on a page with jquery. The goal is a presentation where the elements show the same reaktion on the div element like the mousepointer. So I want to simulate mouseover, click and rightclick events.
Is that possible? Can someone give me an example which show me how to do that?

Thank you for your answers

Lara

P.S.
Example here
[link text](http://jsbin.com/ofewa/edit)
the red square is over an h1 element. Is it possible to execute the h1 mouseover event, when there is a collision of the mypointer and an h1 element?

Comment: You want to simulate the events...or just trigger the event handlers you hooked up to those events?

Comment: I want that if i have an h1 element an I have the code
$("h1").mouseover(function(){
  $("#output").text('I am over the h1 element');
});
that this code will also execute, when the div#mypointer is animated over an h1 element.
If the div have a collision with some element on the page and i call a method on div#mypointer I want that the clickeventhelper of the other element fires and will be execute

Comment: There isn't a collision event in javascript (that I know of) that will fire when two elements meet. You will probably have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I get you well, but to 'simulate' events like `mouseover` et cetera, you can always use jQuery's [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) in a form like:

```
$('#my_div_id').trigger('mouseover');
```

You can also call a more 'detailed' version, where you can specify the events arguments

```
$('#my_div_id').trigger({
   type:    'keypress',
   which:   13,
   ctrlKey: true
});
```

which infact would simulate a return key while `ctrl key` is pressed to 'my_div_id'. If you just need the event handler code to execute, use .[triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i don't understand your idea completely, but i wrote some code.

It works very simple. We bind two events "click mouseover" on #mypointer and also on h1 (or any other selector). When the event fires on #mypointer we check every h1 element to match it's position with position of #mypointer and if match -- trigger the event on matched element.

```
"use strict";
/*global $*/
function getElementCoordinates(el) {
  return {
    left: el.offsetLeft,
    right: el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth,
    top: el.offsetTop,
    bottom: el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight
  };
}
```

```
function checkIntersection($el) {
  var pointer = getElementCoordinates($('#mypointer')[0]);
  var element = getElementCoordinates($el[0]);

  if ((pointer.left >= element.left && pointer.left = element.left && pointer.right = element.bottom && pointer.bottom = element.bottom && pointer.top 



$(function () {
  $('#mypointer').live('click mouseover', function (e) {
    //here write selectors you want to check for collision
    $('h1').each(function () {
      if (checkIntersection($(this))) {
        $(this).trigger(e.type);
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
  $('h1').live('click mouseover', function (e) {
    $("#output").html(e.type + ' fired on ' + e.target.nodeName);
  });
});
```

Sorry, parser "eat" checkIntersection function, so full code available on http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?263utdc1nmqy

wbr,
Roman.

Comment: Thank you for you work.
I did not search for an element mypointer which reacts to my mousepointer and trigger the events to an other element. I ask for the possibility that an other element react to mypointer like to the mousepointer

Comment: Element react to mouse cursor?